# centos 7 nginx phpmyadmin not found

Tags: nginx, centos

access link : http://142.93.60.127/phpmyadmin

my phpmyadmin.conf file is

```
server {
        listen   80;
        server_name 142.93.60.127;


location /phpmyadmin {
        index  index.php;
        root /usr/share/phpMyAdmin;
}

## Images and static content is treated different
        location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|xml)$ {
        access_log        off;
        expires           30d;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
}

location ~ /(libraries|setup/frames|setup/libs) {
        deny all;
        return 404;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/phpMyAdmin$fastcgi_script_name;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I have this problem it's a permissions issue.

Make sure you have the correct permissions on the /usr/share/phpMyAdmin directory and the files in it. The user that nginx is running on needs execute access to the directories and read access to the files.

Also try moving your "root" flag outside of the location flag:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name 142.93.60.127;
    root /usr/share/phpMyAdmin;


    location / {
        index  index.php;
    }

....
}
```

Comment: Also, the CentOS web root is generally `/var/www/`. You might consider installing phpmyadmin there instead of /usr/share.

Comment: my configuration is ok ?

Comment: Updated answer... Try moving your root outside of the `location` flag. Also the locations are relative to your root, so unless you have a folder `/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/phpmyadmin` then that first location should probably just be `/`.

Answer (score -1):

I solve this problem and write a blog about this

[solution](https://www.blog.tutexp.com/how-to-setup-phpmyadmin-in-nginx-centoos-7-5/)